# Cannot connect my AWS EC2 Instance to my GitHub Webhook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, webhooks, github-actions

How I should be able to add two port numbers to my new Inbound Rule for the GitHub webhook I created with the **Type being Custom TCP**, the **Protocol being TCP**, the **Port Range being 8080**, and most importantly, the ***Source being Anywhere with two custom source ports of 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0*** which is seen below in a screenshot of the specific reference from the course itself:
[image]

Then when I try and do the same for my EC2 Instance's Inbound Rules, I can only add one source for the port range of 8080 as seen below...
[image]

As a result, I cannot have ***both 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 connected to port range 8080 simultaneously as seen again below for clarification***
[image]

When I try and do so, I am forced into creating two separate Inbound Rules, both being Custom TCP, Port Range 8080, and the Source of ***each directing to 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 independent of each other, not under one unified Inbound Rule***

As a result, I believe this is why I am not capable of creating an established webhook from my GitHub repo to my AWS EC2 instance.

For more clarification, the course itself is walking me through how to properly setup a webhook from GitHub to my newly created AWS EC2 in conjunction with the [directions here in the very detailed and well-written Strapi documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/amazon-aws.html#set-up-a-webhook), however, after I have followed these directions and have properly created a webhook.js file within my NodeWebHooks file of my root SSH, this is the error I get when I try to establish the connection which is most probably because of the inability to setup my Inbound Rule properly per the additional directive of the course.

As I still try and attempt to follow the documentation with two separate Inbound Rules from Port 8080 with a source of 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 respectively, in accordance with the guide, in my root SSH I enter:
`echo $PATH`
and copy and paste the path within the file of:
`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/webhook.service`

in the proper script as below:

[image]
or as code, it is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Github webhook
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=PATH=/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodejs /home/ubuntu/NodeWebHooks/webhook.sj
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then when I save and exit from that file, in order to enable it, I do:
`sudo systemctl enable webhook.service`
and receive the appropriate desired response of "Created symlink ... etc..." where it clarifies that a webhook.service has been created.
***However, then when I run the following:***

```
sudo systemctl start webhook
sudo systemctl status webhook
```

I get an error which states the following:
[image]
or alternatively, as code it is the following response:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-74:~$ sudo systemctl start webhook
ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-74:~$ sudo systemctl status webhook
● webhook.service - Github webhook
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webhook.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-10-02 22:45:47 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 27129 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodejs /home/ubuntu/NodeWebHooks/webhook.sj (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 27129 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 02 22:45:47 ip-172-31-3-74 systemd[1]: webhook.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 02 22:45:47 ip-172-31-3-74 systemd[1]: webhook.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 02 22:45:47 ip-172-31-3-74 systemd[1]: webhook.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 02 22:45:47 ip-172-31-3-74 systemd[1]: webhook.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 02 22:45:47 ip-172-31-3-74 systemd[1]: Stopped Github webhook.
Oct 02 22:45:47 ip-172-31-3-74 systemd[1]: webhook.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 02 22:45:47 ip-172-31-3-74 systemd[1]: webhook.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 02 22:45:47 ip-172-31-3-74 systemd[1]: Failed to start Github webhook.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely that the `webhook.service` file references under `[Service]`: `home/ubuntu/NodeWebHooks/webhook.sj`, when it is probably named `/home/ubuntu/NodeWebHooks/webhook.js`. It's the little things that get you!